# System.InvalidOperationException : Unable to create new service: ChromeDriverService with ChromeDriver and SeleniumGrid on local machine

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, selenium-grid

I had set up Selenium Grid (Both Hub and Node) on my local machine which runs on Windows 10 using below command for registering Hub.

```
java -jar selenium-server-standalone-3.141.59.jar -role hub
```

and for registering a Node, I had used below command

```
java -jar selenium-server-standalone-3.141.59.jar -role node -hub http://10.37.34.2:4444/grid/register -port 5454
```

On Command Prompt, it displayed that "The node is registered to the hub and ready to use"

Verified Grid Console as well at http://localhost:4444/grid/console.
Everything looked fine.

When I executed a simple test case in visual studio, I saw the below error message.

Result Message:

```
System.InvalidOperationException : Unable to create new service: ChromeDriverService
Build info: version: '3.141.59', revision: 'e82be7d358', time: '2018-11-14T08:25:53'
System info: host: 'PCD-F3FD2', ip: '10.37.34.2', os.name: 'Windows 10', os.arch: 'x86', os.version: '10.0', java.version: '1.8.0_172'
Driver info: driver.version: unknown (SessionNotCreated)
```

On the Hub Command Prompt, I can see

```
"20:47:46.539 INFO [RequestHandler.process] - Got a request to create a new session: Capabilities {browserName: chrome, goog:chromeOptions: {}, platformName: windows}
20:47:46.542 INFO [TestSlot.getNewSession] - Trying to create a new session on test slot {server:CONFIG_UUID=0c4146b1-d7d9-4f39-91ce-b30c57c53342, seleniumProtocol=WebDriver, browserName=chrome, maxInstances=5, platformName=WIN10, platform=WIN10}"
```

On the Node Command Prompt, I can see

```
20:47:46.601 INFO [ActiveSessionFactory.apply] - Capabilities are: {
"browserName": "chrome",
"goog:chromeOptions": {
},
"platformName": "windows"}


20:47:46.602 INFO [ActiveSessionFactory.lambda$apply$11] - Matched factory org.openqa.selenium.grid.session.remote.ServicedSession$Factory (provider: org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriverService)
```

Below is my C# code:

```
[Test]
    public void AccessGoogle()
    {

        ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
        options.BinaryLocation = @"C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe";
        options.PlatformName = PlatformType.Windows.ToString();

        IWebDriver d = new RemoteWebDriver(new Uri("http://10.37.34.2:4444/wd/hub"), options.ToCapabilities());

        d.Manage().Timeouts().ImplicitWait = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(30);

        d.Url = "https://www.google.com/";
    }
```

Could you please help me to understand what went wrong?

I had tweaked my machines Firewall settings as well. But no luck!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you have set up *Selenium Grid (Both Hub and Node)* on your local machine, so while initializng the *Selenium Grid Node* you need to pass the  *absolute path* of the *ChromeDriver* location through the **`Dwebdriver.chrome.driver`** argument as follows:

```
java -Dwebdriver.chrome.driver=C:\path\to\chromedriver.exe -jar selenium-server-standalone-3.141.59.jar -role node -hub http://10.37.34.2:4444/grid/register -port 5454
```

Comment: Thanks, @DebanjanB.
This solution has worked.

It had opened the browser but does nothing. Not even entering the URL.

Comment: @Abhi3106 Can you raise a new question with your new requirement please?

Comment: Sure. Thank you, DebanjanB

Comment: @DebanjanB is it necessary to mention static path for chromedriver.exe ?
cant it be dynamic.

Comment: @Amey It can be dynamic but ensure the effective path is equivalent to the actual path.

Comment: ok, Also my node is some different VM. and I have installed chrome in it. so still I will need to mention path ?
    DesiredCapabilities capabilities = new DesiredCapabilities("chrome",77.0.3865.90", new Platform(PlatformType.Any));
            capabilities.SetCapability(CapabilityType.BrowserName, "chrome");
            capabilities.SetCapability(CapabilityType.Platform, new Platform(PlatformType.Windows));
          
            driver = new RemoteWebDriver(new Uri(" http://172.11.111.111:5556/wd/hub"), capabilities);